# Django objects.get()

Tags: python, django

What if there is nothing that matches the get? Then it returns in an error.

How do I say: get if there is, otherwise, return nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a shortcut like this (based on get_object_or_404):

```
from django.shortcuts import _get_queryset

def get_object_or_none(klass, *args, **kwargs):
  queryset = _get_queryset(klass)
  try:
    return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
  except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
    return None
```

Not sure why this shortcut doesn't exist (perhaps someone with more django under their belt can explain) as it is a reasonably useful shortcut that I use from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `try/except` or [`get_object_or_404`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Answer (score 2):

or you can try django annoying

```
pip install django-annoying
```

then import get_object_or_None(klass, *args, **kwargs)

```
from annoying.functions import get_object_or_None
get_object_or_None(User, email='test@test.com')
```

Here is the project [repo on github](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying)